# Extract data from Field Collection using db_select()

Tags: database, entities

I'd like to use db_select() to extract values from a field collection attached to the user profile, to help speed up some complex Ajax forms (rather than loading the entire field collection, using standard entity queries, etc, etc).

Assuming I have the following:

Field Collection: `field_my_address`
Field 1: `field_street_number` (integer field)
Field 2: `field_street_name` (text field)
Field 3: `field_city` (taxonomy term reference field)

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is slightly too broad. Revisions necessary? But basically, my first stop when doing Drupal 7 db stuff is to look at the [Dynamic Queries](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries) as well as understanding the field schema (field/revision).

Comment: Not interested in revisions; however, I'll browse through that reference and see what I can find... Standard queries, I've been ok with, but FC's are causing me pain!

Comment: Without revisions, then you can join in field tables via `field_data_[FIELD_NAME]` e.g. `field_data_field_street_name` and make sure that entity_id and entity_type are set. My one gotcha there is that if you use a placeholder for entity_type, there's a bug (or hidden feature?) where you can only set the same placeholder name once. (Edit) You'll also need to look up the field storage schema (hook_field_schema) for those fields, but I think the columns would be `FIELD_NAME_value` and `FIELD_NAME_tid` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work like this:

```
$pid = $profile->pid;

$query = db_query('SELECT nn.field_street_number_value AS number,
                          ss.field_field_street_name_value AS street, 
                          cc.field_city_tid AS city, 
         FROM field_data_field_my_address AS aa
         LEFT JOIN field_data_field_street_number AS nn ON aa.field_my_address_value = nn.entity_id 
         LEFT JOIN field_data_field_street_name AS ss ON aa.field_my_address_value = ss.entity_id 
         LEFT JOIN field_data_field_city AS cc ON aa.field_my_address_value = cc.entity_id 
         WHERE aa.entity_id = '.$pid);

$records = $query->fetchAll();
```